# Connectedness of $\mathbb{C} \setminus E$ given $E$ is connected.

Tags: connectedness

Suppose that $E \subset \mathbb{C}$ is connected. Is it true that $\mathbb{C} \setminus E$ is also connected ?

The only few examples I have tell me it seems True but maybe there is a simple counter-example or a simple proof to this. Any help ?

Comment: What if $E$ is the $x$-axis?

Comment: Ooh right ! And if $E$ is bounded do we have the result ?

Comment: What is $E$ is a circle?

Comment: If $E$ is a circle, then $\mathbb{C} \backslash \left\{E\right\}$ is ( path )connected

Comment: Atmos, not a ball, but think of $|z|=1$.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, thank you